# ORA-24344: success with compilation error, why?

Tags: oracle-apex

```
create or replace function calcul_price( int a, int b) return int
AS
    int summa := 0;
begin
    summa := a + b;
    return summa;
end;
```

I don't understand where I made a mistake, please help me.

Comment: Show error(s), please.

Comment: Use `show errors` or query the `user_errors` view to see the details of the compilation errors. But `int summa := 0;` should be `summa int := 0;`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Variable declaration syntax was not correct.
Please check link https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/overview.htm#BABEABGF

Please check below correct code.

```
   create or replace function calcul_price(a int ,b int ) return int
   AS 
        summa int := 0;
   begin
        summa := a + b;
        return summa;
   end;
```

Hope this will help you!.